# 404 in Jersey/Struts application

Tags: java, jersey, struts

I am trying to use Jersey to provide a simple web service for my struts application.

When I call the client action I get the following error

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException
Message: GET http://localhost:8080/shumer/rest/employee/get returned a response status of 404
```

servlet declaration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.autowire</param-name>
        <param-value>byName</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Server resource

```
@Path("employee")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @Autowired
    EmpDao empDao;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Employee> get(@QueryParam("empCode") String empCode) throws Exception {

            EmpCriteria criteria = new EmpCriteria();
            criteria.setEmpCode(empCode);


            return empDao.searchByCondition(criteria);
        }

}
```

Client action

```
public class EmployeeClientTestAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/shumer/rest/employee/get");

        String employees= resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(String.class);

        System.out.println(employees);

        request.setAttribute("employees", employees);

        return mapping.findForward("successful");
    }

}
```

I have tried this with and without the `/get` and the end of the resource url, and with and without a leading `/` in the EmployeeResource @Path annotation. My guess is that there is somewhere I have to declare where my resources are lcoated at in order for the Jersey servlet to handle them, but I can't figure it out. A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have added the following init-param to the servlet element and it is still not working (this package is where my resource class is)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>shumer.rest.resource</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: which version of jersey you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

in get method write   @Path("/get")